# rpi3 bitcoin full node missing wallet commands

Tags: bitcoind

I built a bitcoin full node from 0.15.0.1 that is missing the wallet commands:

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ bitcoin-cli help getwalletinfo

help: unknown command: getwalletinfo

It synced the blockchain fine. I used the instructions here: http://www.raspberrypifullnode.com/

Any suggestions of what might have caused this omission?

Answer (score 3):

The instructions you're linking to include the line

```
./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/include -O2" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.8/lib" --disable-wallet
```

The `--disable-wallet` in that line (surprise!) disables the wallet functionality, making the node purely act as a P2P participant.

If you want a wallet, you need to configure enabling the wallet support.

Comment: Duh! That's what I get for blindly cut and pasting. (Strange that no wallet is the default). Greatly appreciated Pieter!

Comment: Note that the only way I could get this to build the wallet was to add  the 

"--with-incompatible-bdb"

option to the above ./configure command.